# How to get data from other collection in springboot

Tags: java, json, mongodb, spring-boot, microservices

I am create springboot project and use a mongodb as a database.Now I have 2 collection

User collection

```java
@Data
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {
  @Id
  private int user_id;
  private String user_name;
  private int product_id
}
```

Document in User Collection

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 0,
    "user_name": "bob",
    "product_id: 001
  }
]
```

---

Product Collection

```java
@Data
@Document(collection = "product")
public class Product {
@Id
  private int product_id;
  private String product_name;
  private double price; 
}
```

Document in Product Collection

```
[
  {
    "product_id": 001,
    "product_name": "Coconut",
    "price": 20.00
  }
]
```

---

And this is the result that I want, when I use "GET" method in User Collection

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 0,
    "user_name": "bob",
    "product: [
                {
                  "product_id": 001,
                  "product_name": "Coconut",
                  "price": 20.00
                }
              ],
  }
]
```

Or any result that can get all values of Product where "product_id" = 001

PS : On insert data. Insert data by table. product_id is String ( "product_id":001 ) not as Object ( "product_id":[...] )

PS : My English is not well, if you have any questions you can ask more

Comment: can u use relational db?

Comment: Yes, I can use relational db in mySQL

Comment: what is your problem , do you want to get records in single call or 2 call is also good for you ?

Comment: u can use oneToMany relation between user and product. and ur orm load what u want

Comment: I want to get the records in single call. It have a data from User Collection and Product Collect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the JSON response like this:

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 0,
    "user_name": "bob",
    "product: [
                {
                  "product_id": 001,
                  "product_name": "Coconut",
                  "price": 20.00
                }
              ], <---- not comma here
  }
]
```

you should change the structures of your classes accordingly;

**User Class**

```java
@Data
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {
  @Id
  private int user_id;
  private String user_name;
  private List<Product> product;
}
```

**Product Class**

```java
@Data
@Document(collection = "product")
public class Product {
@Id
  private int product_id;
  private String product_name;
  private double price; 
}
```

You probably use Jackson library, it will automatically serialize now as you want.

Comment: I've tried it, but when I want to insert a data. I want a product(user collection) as a List<String> or List<Int>, not a Object. For the Example. "product":[ 001,002 ]

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do that is using [@DBRef](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/DBRef.html):

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String username;
  @JsonProperty("products")
  @DBRef
  private List<Product> productList;
}


@Data
@Document(collection = "product")
public class Product {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String productName;
  private double price; 
}
```

Here is an article that shows how to use it properly https://www.baeldung.com/cascading-with-dbref-and-lifecycle-events-in-spring-data-mongodb